# Open views Microsoft Dynamics CRM mobile client (for Phones) with a URL

Tags: android, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm am trying to open a view from an application in Dynamics CRM. Here is my code :

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("ms-dynamicsxrm://?pagetype=create&etn=account"));
launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

It opens the CRM mobile application but not on the right form or view. It opens home screen. Does someone know how to do that ?

Here is the doc from Microsoft : [Extend Microsoft Dynamics CRM on the client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607595.aspx#Example)

Thank you for the help

Comment: Sounds like a product bug to me. I guess, none of other `pagetype`'s  works? I'd suggest to contact [Technical Support](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/contact-technical-support.aspx) if you haven't already done it.

Comment: The article you refer to applies to "CRM 2016 on-prem, CRM Online". Are you sure you are on that version? (Maybe you need to review your tags.)

Comment: I was on 2015 for some tests and I forgot to change, grrr. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for any other version than 2016. According to this release note from MS, it is enabled in the CRM 2016 release (for both online and on-prem customers) according to this Microsoft article (tab: fall 2015)

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/get-ready-for-the-next-release.aspx#bkmk_NewFeaturesAra

Search for app-to-app deep linking:

> App-to-app deep linking: Other mobile apps (such as email or your
>   custom web-based app) can now link directly to a record, view, or
>   dashboard in CRM mobile apps.

The article you link yourself also states at the top:

> Applies To: CRM 2016 on-prem, CRM Online

It is also mentioned in this 2016 Preview:

http://cargas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Microsoft_Dynamics_CRM_2016_Release_Preview_Guide.pdf

> **App-to-app deep linking**  Enables other mobile apps (such as email or your custom mashup apps) to link and directly navigate to a record,
>   view or dashboard within the CRM mobile app. In simple terms, this
>   provides a URL addressable form/view/dashboard for mobile scenarios.

The introduction section specify that the capabilities listed are only for CRM 2016.